# Which pins are represented by these constants from ABR library?

Tags: attiny, uart, attiny13

The following code comes from [AtTiny serial library](https://github.com/MarcelMG/AVR8_BitBang_UART_TX) that I want to use:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

// change these to use another pin
#define TX_PORT PORTB
#define TX_PIN  PB0
#define TX_DDR  DDRB
#define TX_DDR_PIN DDB0
```

I have no idea which pins to connect. What do these constants mean and where are they documented?

Comment: On the ATTiny13 PB0 is on physical pin 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping can be found in the io.h file but also in Arduino core files.

Below is the pin mapping:

```
                        ATtinyX4
                      +----U----+
  (VCC)-------------1-|VCC   GND|-14------------(GND)
  (D10)-------------2-|PB0   PA0|-13----------(D0/A0)
  (D9)--------------3-|PB1   PA1|-12----------(D1/A1)
  (/RESET)----------4-|PB3   PA2|-11----------(D2/A2)
  (D8)--------------5-|PB2   PA3|-10-------(D3/A3/SS)
  (D7/A7)-----------6-|PA7   PA4|-9---(D4/A4/SCL/SCK)
  (MISO/SDA/D6/A6)--7-|PA6   PA5|-8------(D5/A5/MOSI)
                      +---------+
```

The serial library uses:

```
#define TX_PIN  PB0
```

Which is `ATtinyX4 Pin #2`, or Arduino attiny core digital pin `D10` https://github.com/damellis/attiny/blob/master/variants/tiny14/pins_arduino.h.

Cheers

Comment: Question is about ATTiny13

Comment: @Gerben No the tag. The actual source code mentioned is ATtinyX4. But in any case the same "lookup" is required.

Comment: All his other questions are about the 13A. I don't think that library will work on an ATTiny13A. At the very least, the library assumes it runs at 8MHz, while the 13A runs at 9.6MHz. He'd have to change the `OCR0A = 103;` with something like `123`.

Comment: @Gerben Thanks for pointing that out. I know that the library isn't meant specifically for 13A, but I cannot find anything else, so I decided to try to get that to work.